# Resume adjustment

Tags: resume

The company I worked for outsourced my work to another company but all of us went with the new company. We do the same work and represent the original company with their letters and such.  But our paychecks are from this new company (3rd party company). same work but different company on my check. I'm not sure how i put this on my resume. I worked for the first company for 10yrs and started with this new company in Nov, 2016.

Comment: It is not clear what you want us to tell you. You seem to be clearly aware that your employer changed from the old to the new company, so what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

They are a new employer, you list them as such. If you want in the description mention that the client you support is the same as your previous employer.